# Is it possible to have two browser windows opened simultaneously with different sessions?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, session

Is it possible to have two browser (IE and FF mainly) windows opened simultaneously with different HTTP sessions for the same web application? I think I remember that this actually was the standard way back then in IE 6.

Comment: You should state that **two browsers** should be of the same kind (either two IE or two FF). Because mixing of course works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In IE8 and above, you could open multiple instances of this browser by running it with the `-nomerge` parameter. This way, session cookies will be separate for each instance. (source: [IEBlog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/05/06/session-cookies-sessionstorage-and-ie8.aspx))

For Firefox, there are several ways to achieve the same result, as [listed here on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/41496/firefox-using-multiple-instances-with-different-profiles)

Chrome/Chromium and Opera have Private Mode, in which session cookies aren't shared with other windows of the same browser (create a Private window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>)

Tested in all of the above; note that this is universally valid only for **session** cookies (those which expire when you close the browser) - persistent cookies are handled slightly differently in each browser.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from IE 8.0 -nomerge is deprecated, use -noframemerging instead, see [IE CL options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).